# Fullcalendar unable to drag and drop events in a day of basic week view

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I have been  assigned a project with calendar implementation in Angular js framework.

I integrated fullcalendar 3.8.0  with Angular JS and it is working fine. 
But customer requires to drag and drop or order events within a day vertically.
 e.g:  basicWeek view.

```
Mon 1/8
job three
job two
job one.
```

The customer wants to drag the event 'job three' presented at first position and drop after 'job one' event vertically within the day (Mon 1/8).
e.g:
    Mon 1/8

```
job two
job one.
job three
```

The above is not possible at the moment with fullCalendar.

[Please find the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KZnm.png)

Below are the files I am using for fullCalendar integration with Angular JS

```
   librarires

    moment.js
    jquery-1.11.3.js
    angular.js
    ngDraggable.js
    calendar.js
    fullcalendar.js    
    gcal.js

    Style Sheet 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css3/fullcalendar.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" />

     //Dragable events
    <div class="col-" ng-repeat="obj in draggableObjects" ng-drag="true"
            ng-drag-data="obj" data-allow-transform="false">{{obj.title}}

  </div>
                        //Calendar binding in UI with Controller
                  <div>
                            <div id="calendar_one"
                                ng-drop-success="onDropComplete1($data,$event)"
                                ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources"
                                calendar="myCalendar">
                                <div ng-repeat="obj in eventSources" ng-drag="true"
                                    ng-drag-data="obj" ng-center-anchor="{{centerAnchor}}">{{obj.title}}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

//Angular JS Controller                         

var app = angular.module("myApp", [ "ui.calendar", "ngDraggable" ]);

app.controller("myNgController", [ "$rootScope", "$scope", "$window",      "$document", "$timeout", "uiCalendarConfig",  
    function($rootScope, $scope, $window, $document, $timeout,  uiCalendarConfig) {

     $scope.dateRangesSOM = ["Jan 08, 2018 - Jan 12, 2018", "Jan 15, 2018 - Jan 19, 2018"]
     $scope.selectedDateRange = $scope.dateRangesSOM[0] ;        
     $scope.droppableObjectsDate = new Date();
        /**
         * Draggable objects code starts here
         */


        $scope.draggableObjects = [ {
            title : "Job Name One- #H",
            description : "Operation New Submittal",
            start: $scope.droppableObjectsDate,
            end : $scope.droppableObjectsDate,
            allDay : true
        }, {
            title : "Long Lead Time Name 2- #H",
            description : "Operation New Submittal",
            start : $scope.droppableObjectsDate,
            end : $scope.droppableObjectsDate,
            allDay : true
        }

        ];

        /**
         * Calendar code starts here
         */

        /*
         * Calendar 01
         */

        $scope.SelectedEvent = null;



        $scope.events = [];
        $scope.eventSources = [ $scope.events ];


        // Create dummy data
        var eventEntities = [ {
            title : "Job Name One- #H",
            description : "Operation New Submittaly",
            start :  $scope.droppableObjectsDate ,
            end :   $scope.droppableObjectsDate ,
            allDay : true
        }
        , {
            title : "Long Lead Time Name 2- #H",
            description : "Operation New Submittaly",
            start :   $scope.droppableObjectsDate ,
            end :   $scope.droppableObjectsDate ,
            allDay : true
        } ];


        // For existing events 
        angular.forEach(eventEntities, function(value, key) {

            console.log("Key is " + key + " Value is " + value);
            $scope.events.push({
                title : value.title,
                description : value.description,
                start : value.start,
                end : value.end,
                allDay : value.allDay
            })
        });


        /**
         * Drop functionality
         */         
        $scope.onDropComplete1 = function(data, evt) {
            console.log("One Drop complete "+data + " "+evt.start);

            var index = $scope.events.indexOf(data);

            if (index == -1)
                $scope.events.push(data);               

        }


        // Configure Calendar

        $scope.uiConfig = {
            // Configuring calendar, its look and feel
            calendar : {

                // height : 450,
                height : 200,
                editable : true,
                displayEventTime : true,
                droppable: true, 
                dropAccept:true,
                draggable: true,
                weekends:false,
                eventOrder:"",
                startEditable: true,
                overlap : true,              

                selectable:true,
                selectHelper:true,


                select: function(start, end){
                console.log("Select event"+start);  
                },

                header : {

                    left : "basicWeek",
                    center : "",                        
                    right : ""
                },

                eventClick : function(event) {
                    console.log("Event eventClick...");
                    $scope.SelectedEvent = event;
                },

                eventRender: function(event, element, view){                    

                    console.log("eventRendered. view.start...."+view.start);
                    console.log("eventRendered. view.end...."+view.end);
                },


                eventDrop: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view){
                    console.log("Event Droppped..."+event.start);


                },

                eventDragStop: function(event){
                    console.log("eventDragStop() event ..."+event.start);
                },

                eventDragStart: function(event){
                console.log("eventDragStart() event ..."+event.start);
                }


            }

        }

        /**
         * EOF
         */
    } ]);
```

Comment: dragging and dropping, and ordering are two separate concepts. By definition, if you drag an event, then you're explicitly setting its position and not relying on an automatic ordering function. Show your code and explain more clearly what you're trying to do. Bear in mind also that eventOrder only applies at all when two events have exactly the same start and end dates/times. If those don't match then the ordering isn't applied, because again by definition (this being a calendar) they are ordered by the date/time. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventOrder/

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.

Here I need to drag an event in a day and drop in the same cell vertically. No need of any order.

Comment: Why are you talking about eventOrder then? Please clarify your question and show what you've tried to do already to solve this. There is a lot of documentation on fullCalendar relating to dragging and dropping, as well as live demos for which you can look at the code. If you're not interested in the ordering, then please explain what the actual problem is.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you very much for your response. I edited the code and exact requirement in description section. Could you please help me out as this is a immediate requirement for me to achieve. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code mentions jquery-1.11.3.js ...In the docs at https://fullcalendar.io/support/ it's stated you need jquery 2.0 or above. Anyway, from your screenshot, you appear to be using a "basic" type view. If you want to drag things within a day, you need to use an "agenda" view.  The reason it doesn't work in a "basic" view is simply because when you drop the event, the system has no way to know what start time you wanted to change it to, because the "basic" view has no time series on the left. Therefore it's logically impossible to do what you're suggesting in that context.

Comment: If you switch to the "week" view in this demo https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.8.0/demos/selectable.html you can see it's possible to drag and drop events within a single day. However I also note that you've set all your events to "allDay: true" which means they don't have a time component (or, it is ignored), so you can't move them around anyway. They'll just appear in the order you sent them to the calendar, I think.

Comment: Actually I think if they are all-day, they will appear in the order defined by eventOrder (so your original comment about it was sort of relevant, if a bit garbled), which by default is alphabetical. You can potentially override it, but it's not dynamic - it just applies when the events are first loaded. You still can't drag them around within the day, because they don't have a time component and you're also using a view which doesn't deal with time.

Comment: @ADyson, Thank you for your support! I know this can be achieved by using 'AgendaWeek' but it includes time compoents (hours) in view, where my given requirement it does not. Anyway, Thanks you very much.

Comment: Well then you have a choice. Does your requirement explicitly state that you must _not_ show time components? Or does it simply not mention it? If it just doesn't mention it, then you can legitimately include it because it's necessary to provide the required functionality, and you would not be in breach of the requirement. If you've been specifically told you can't put times into the screen, then you should probably challenge the requirement (it's a bit over-specific anyway IMO!) and say it's not achievable without using time slots.

Comment: Although, like I said, if all your events are `allDay: true` then the time stuff doesn't matter, and you simply can't drag those kinds of events within a day, because there's no logical basis on which to do that.